# Is there any ways to assign different local IP other than "127.0.0.1" for multiple connected devices?

Tags: adb

So i have a software for automated testing, and i need to connect with the device IP and forward to some port to work. But with wired, every device has the same localhost IP "127.0.0.1".

I've tried the tcp route (wireless), but it takes too long to response, around3-8 seconds which is not good enough for my test cases.

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server

adb -s <device A id>  forward tcp:5555 tcp:5555
adb -s <device A id>  forward tcp:5554 tcp:5554
adb -s <device A id>  forward tcp:5553 tcp:5553

adb -s <device B id>  forward tcp:5555 tcp:5555
adb -s <device B id>  forward tcp:5554 tcp:5554
adb -s <device B id>  forward tcp:5553 tcp:5553
```

This will result in only one device got port forwardedf for localhost (127.0.0.1)

So how can i change the localhost IP of these devices  when connect via wired?

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, i can assign different ports for the devices with the same localhost ip:

```
adb -s <device A id>  forward tcp:5545 tcp:5555
adb -s <device B id>  forward tcp:5535 tcp:5555
```